# Content down left side of page (HTML)

Tags: html

How do I run a strip of html content vertically down the left side of the page? Similar to a a navigation menu in a way.

The content I want to put in the strip is
 `<a href="http://windoge8.ga">- About Windoge 8 os</a>`

(I'm using it for online game that I am making)
A solution that is only HTML is preferable.

Comment: Man you really should write about the efforts you already did instead of lol'ing and apologizing. Please read the FAQ about how you should ask questions here. Regarding your problem, i recommend not to use the html tag div or iframe for the basic structure. E.g. create 2 div's in your html body, call them "navbar" and "mainwindow", style them to fit your needs and fill them with contents.

Comment: Sorry, that should mean that i do recommend to use "div" or "iframe", just ignore the "not"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using "[float](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)" css attribute:

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 200px; background: green">
    <div style="float: left; width: 200px; height: 100%; background: yellow">Left Stuff</div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 200px; height: 100%">Right Stuff</div>
    <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

See a running example at [codepen](https://codepen.io/ryanmarten/pen/WMZpgK) that I made.

Answer (score 1):

You could use transforms in your css like this: `transform: rotate(90deg);`

Comment: Sorry, i'm using HTML! But thanks, i'll keep it in mind if I ever use CSS ;)

Comment: You could use the same transform as a style in your html as well. You wouldn't need a separate css page.